# When designing an API, when does one use and not use generics?

Tags: generics, jakarta-ee, api-design

E.g., looking at [the Java EE 5 documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/) for javax.persistence.EntityManager, why is the persist method declared as `void persist(Object entity)` but the merge method as `<T> T merge(T entity)`?  Doesn't it seem inconsistent or asymmetric that persist isn't generified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `persist` method can take any kind of object (*) and returns `void`. There is no variation.

The `merge` method returns an object of the same class as its parameter. In order to convey that, they need to use generics.

(*) Of course, it needs to be an Entity, but that is not related to the class hierarchy (it is managed by annotations, not by marker interfaces).

Answer (score 1):

The merge declaration forces de user of the API to pass a type as parameter compatible with the return type, although inside the method JPA doesn't take advance of the generics (since it still need reflection).

For the persist method, the problem is that

```
 void persist (T entity)
```

Is exactly as expressive as

```
 void persist (Object entity)
```

Since the user of the API can still pass any object inside, and since the generics are not used inside the method (JPA still need to use reflection).